# jquery UI datepicker- multiple selection functionality

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a datepicker. When I select a date, automatically next two days should also get selected. In total, 3 business days should get selected.
I have tried below code but it's not working.

```
$('.date-pick').datePicker({
    createButton:false,
    displayClose:true,
    closeOnSelect:false,
    selectMultiple:true,
    numSelectable:3
});
```

Comment: Please clarify further. Any 3 days? next 3 business days? Holidays count? Please be as specific as possible. This will be done in the `select` callback, what have you tried so far?

Comment: next 3 business days

Answer (score 0):

Your post did not include a details about the output or selection process. Here is an example for your review:

```js
$(function() {
  function dayNumOfWeek(d) {
    var week = {
      "Sun": 0,
      "Mon": 1,
      "Tue": 2,
      "Wed": 3,
      "Thu": 4,
      "Fri": 5,
      "Sat": 6,
    }
    return week[d];
  }

  $(".date-pick").datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true,
    closeText: "Close",
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    onSelect: function(dt) {
      var myDays = [
        new Date(dt),
        new Date(dt),
        new Date(dt)
      ];
      var dow = myDays[0].getDay();
      var dp = $(".date-pick");
      console.log("Selected: " + dow + "/7, " + dt, myDays);

      switch (dow) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
          console.log("mtw");
          myDays[1].setDate(myDays[1].getDate() + 1);
          myDays[2].setDate(myDays[2].getDate() + 2);
          break;
        case 4:
          console.log("rfm");
          myDays[1].setDate(myDays[1].getDate() + 1);
          myDays[2].setDate(myDays[2].getDate() + 4);
          break;
        case 5:
          console.log("fmt");
          myDays[1].setDate(myDays[1].getDate() + 3);
          myDays[2].setDate(myDays[2].getDate() + 4);
          break;
      };
      var fDT = [];
      console.log("Format Dates");
      var mm, dd, yy;
      for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        console.log(i, myDays[i]);
        mm = myDays[i].getMonth() + 1;
        dd = myDays[i].getDate();
        yy = myDays[i].getFullYear();
        mm = (mm < 10 ? "0" + mm : mm);
        dd = (dd < 10 ? "0" + dd : dd);
        fDT[i] = mm + "/" + dd + "/" + yy;
      };
      console.log("Formatted:", fDT);
      dp.val(fDT.join(", "));
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Select Date: <input type="text" class="date-pick" />
```

When you make a selection, you can manage what is done via `onSelect` that receives the date in text. Since you are working with business days of the week, mon to fri, and months, you want to make sure that selecting a date near the end of the week and end of the month calculates the next few days properly.

Converting to JavaScript `Date` type, you can leverage a lot of the tools to calculate the next few days without issues. You have 3 scenarios: Mon, Tues, Wed. as 1, Thur, Fri, Mon as 2, and Fri, Mon, Tue as 3.

When you make a selection, it picks the next 2 days from the business week.